# when to use data contract and when to use message contract in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have seen when people work with entity then they decorate their entity classes with [DataContract] attribute

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

see the message contract part

```
[MessageContract]
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string EmpID;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Name;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Designation;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int Salary;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Location;
}
```

Now my question why message contract is required because we can get our job done by data contract only. The only advantage is by message contract we can decide which property will be pass as header property and which one will be pass on as body property.

Just tell me why message contract is required?

When message contract is required?

What are the advantages of message contract?

What are the difference between message contract and data contract and when which one we should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you've already answered to your question by yourself.

> The only advantage is by message contract we can decide which property will be pass as header property and which one will be pass on as body property.

This is true. The only case when you need message contract is when you need full control over a structure of a SOAP message.

Comment: any other difference exist apart from what i said in my post?